# When I run this selenium code with python, google opens for a second and then closes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

im new to coding so I wanna create a small project using selenium but i have a problem. When I run this code it works for a split second and then google closes. Below is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
PATH ="/drivers/chromedriver"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

drivers = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
drivers.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: It is because the script finished all of the things you asked it to do. Therefore it called all of the destructors for the selenium objects (which closed the browser). If you want to maintain the window open while you do more operations you should do `time.sleep(60) # for a minute of time before the program ends`

Answer (score 0):

You are launching the Chrome browser twice, I don't why.

For ChromeDriverManager():

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

For chromedriver.exe:

```
PATH = "/drivers/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH), options=options)
```

You have to use any one of the above codes to launch the browser.

To prevent chrome browser from closing:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

or

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
PATH = "/drivers/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH), options=options)
```